# Average time complexity of finding top-k elements

Tags: algorithm, heap, complexity-theory, time-complexity, top-n

Consider the task of finding the top-k elements in a set of N independent and identically distributed floating point values. By using a priority queue / heap, we can iterate once over all N elements and maintain a top-k set by the following operations:

- if the element x is "worse" than the heap's head: discard x ⇒ complexity O(1)
- if the element x is "better" than the heap's head: remove the head and insert x ⇒ complexity O(log k)

The worst case time complexity of this approach is obviously O(N log k), but what about the average time complexity? Due to the iid-assumption, the probability of the O(1) operation increases over time, and we rarely have to perform the costly O(log k), especially for k << N.

<s>Is this average time complexity documented in any citable reference?</s> What's the average time complexity? If you have a citeable reference for your answer please include it.

Comment: IMO for k << N, the complexity will asymptotically approach O(N).

Comment: I'm fairly sure asking for a 'citable reference' classifies as a recommendation question, which is off topic for [so], as per the [help/on-topic]. Feel free to change your question appropriately.

Comment: @Dukeling: I'm not asking for a recommendation. Should I modify the question in a way that it has a unique answer? For instance, by asking for the _first_ publication, which contains this result? To me, the question is more whether such a reference exists at all.

Comment: The request for a citeable reference is not on topic for this network.  It's fine to ask the question of 'how do I do this/find this/what is this', but if you're really asking for research help, it's not appropriate.

Comment: Meta discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212944/212780).

Comment: Rather than asking for a citation, why's the question not just "what's the average time complexity?" It's not that hard to figure out from first principles (eg: see my answer).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, I am wondering, it might be O(log(n)) in case of k is far less than n, actually, I think the complexity is k*log(n/k), take k is 1, then comes log(n), if k is n, then comes 1, considering we split those n into groups, each group with k numbers max, as less groups as possible, then we have approximately g=n/k groups, two groups together we try to extract top-k, what we have is k elements in order, apart from first time, this costs O(k), repeat, every 2 groups comes to 1 group, repeat this log(g) times, then we have O(k*log(g)), which is O(k*log(n/k))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the i'th largest element, and a particular permutation. It'll inserted into the k-sized heap if it appears before no more than k-1 of the (i - 1) larger elements in the permutation.

The probability of that heap-insertion happening is 1 if i <= k, and k/i if i > k.

From this, you can compute the expectation of the number of heap adjustments, using linearity of expectation. It's sum(i = 1 to k)1 + sum(i = k+1 to n)k/i = k + sum(i = k+1 to n)k/i = k * (1 + H(n) - H(k)), where H(n) is the n'th harmonic number.

This is approximately k log(n) (for k << n), and you can compute your average cost from there.

Comment: If k is large, k * (log n - log k) or k * log (n / k) gives a better result. For example if k = n / 2.