# Distributed Memory Top-K Algorithm for Large K

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing, partial-sort

I have a distributed array of rankings, of total size `N` irregularly distributed amongst `NP` processors, from which I need to extract the `K` largest elements. In the limit that `K << N`, `K` is smaller than any of the local buffer lengths, and `K` is relatively small in general (such that it can e.g. fit in reasonable MPI buffers), the following algorithm seems to work well

1. Perform a local top-K search to determine the largest `K` values in each local array segment
2. Perform a custom Allreduce which performs binary top-K reductions between buffers of size `K` coming from different processes.

This can be done in a semi-communication-optimal way given the communication patterns underlying `MPI_Allreduce`.

I'm unclear how this can be done efficiently without the above assumptions about the size of `K` relative to `N` and the local buffer sizes. In particular, I'm trying to determine an optimal (or reasonably scaling) algorithm that is compatible  with the following:

- `K` can be larger than some or all of the local buffer dimensions
- `K` can be so large is to be impractical to communicate entirely (e.g. trying to determine the top billion elements of a 10 billon element array)

The full array nor the top-`K` elements need to be sorted on completion.

For arrays which reside on a single processing element, the following questions are related:

[Collect top K elements from multiple sorted arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547301/collect-top-k-elements-from-multiple-sorted-arrays)

[Average time complexity of finding top-k elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707209/average-time-complexity-of-finding-top-k-elements)

[Optimal algorithm for returning top k values from an array of length N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956593/optimal-algorithm-for-returning-top-k-values-from-an-array-of-length-n)

Comment: LazySelect should work for this. I posted [a serial implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75258547/2144669) recently, but the parts that operate on the full array would parallelize.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to find the top-`K` repeatedly, where each time you make `K` the largest value satisfying the original assumption.

Assuming you'd want to get top-`K'` where `K'` is greater than the local buffer and MPI communication sizes. You could do the following to eventually find top-`K'`:

1. Find top-`K` where `K` is the greatest value that fits inside local buffer and can be communicated with MPI.
2. Append the `K` elements to the top array `A`, and remove them from the local arrays.
3. Go back to #1 above until `size(A) == K'`.

The resulting array `A` should contain the top-`K'` elements.